# sorting single row dataframe by column values

Tags: python, dataframe, sorting

I have to sort columns in single row dataframe by descending order.

dataframe looks like:

```
   store_1  store_2  store_3
0       11       54       28
```

result should be like:

```
   store_2  store_3  store_1
0       54       28       11
```

dataframe has more than sixty columns.

Comment: yes. one row. sixty columns.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the [pandas.Series.sort_values](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.sort_values.html):

```py
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame(data=[[11,54,28]], columns=['store_1', 'store_2', 'store_3'])
df = df.sort_values(by=0, axis=1, ascending=False)
print(df)
```

output will be:

```
   store_2  store_3  store_1
0       54       28       11
```

Comment: ascending is missing. thank You!!!!

Answer (score 0):

This should work:

```
df.sort_values(by=0,axis=1)
```

where **by** indicates the label or index of the row, and **axis = 1** indicates you want to sort the columns!

Comment: dosen't work. same result.